# Mellin's original paper on his transform

Tags: mathematics

There is no link on wikipedia to his work.

This is really a nice transform. There is coherent theory behind.

I am curious what motivated him to invent this transform.

Answer (score 2):

According to [MacTutor](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Mellin.html),

> He studied the transform which now bears his name and established its reciprocal properties. He applied this technique systematically in a long series of papers to the study of the gamma function, hypergeometric functions,...

and it gives this "long list of papers". I can't say much more because most of these papers are in Swedish. His first paper on Gamma function was published in 1883.

Comment: I see even more papers in Finnish which would be even more difficult to read for most people familiar with "European" languages. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hjalmar_Mellin), he was an outspoken _fennoman_.